# Hosting A Shared Drive - Router Vs. Windows Server 2012

Tags: router, file-sharing, windows-server-2012

I have an external USB harddrive that I want to use as shared drive on my home network. I have two options.

1. Share it through the USB drive sharing features of the router ASUS RT-N65U.
2. Share it by connecting to a Windows 2012 based server that I have on the network.

Which would be better for sharing a large drive reliably across Windows, OSX & Linux clients?

I personally feel that the windows server would be better at this. However, I like the fact that with the router, I don't depend on an actual box to be switched on all the time to host the drive.

Answer (score 0):

the router specs say this
File server: Samba and FTP server with account management
so it would be less resource hungry than a system running windows server, and Samba and FTP allow it to be accessible on all the platforms you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Bahrain! I read that about the router as well. However, do you think it would be good at working with a large drive e.g. 3TB? I couldn't find any discussion on this on the web.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I dont think the size of the drive matters as it is being served through USB 3.0 which has higher bandwidth than your gigabit LAN, approx (3.2Gbps)